# Determining the change of Error when changing the step size $h$ of the Taylor Method for IVPs

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, initial-value-problems, finite-differences

I am given the following IVP that I am to solve numerically using the Taylor method of order 2:
\begin{equation}
\left\{ \begin{array}{cc} 
 y' = \underbrace{ye^x + 1}_{f(x,y(x))}, & \; 0\leq x \leq 1 \\
y(0) = 0.5 &
 \end{array}\right.
\end{equation}
If I am not wrong, using the Taylor method of order 2 we get:
\begin{align*}
y_{k+1} &= y_k + hf(x_k,y_k) + \frac{h^2}{2}\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}|_{x=x_k, y=y_k} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}|_{x=x_k, y=y_k} f(x_k,y_k) 
\right) \\
y_{k+1} &= y_k + h(y_ke^{x_k} +1) + \frac{h^2}{2}\left(e^{x_k}(y_k + y_ke^{x_k} + 1) \right)
\end{align*}

where for $h = 0.5$, we have $x_0 = 0, x_1 = 0.5, x_2 = 1$ and therefore:
\begin{align}
y_1 &= 1.5625 \\
y_2 &= 4.2184
\end{align}
**What I need help with:** I am then asked if we were to use another step size of $h = 0.125$ (which is a quarter of the initial $h$), by what factor would we expect (approximately) the error rate to decrease?

My guess is that $E_{h = 0.125} \approx \frac{E_{h = 0.5}}{16}$

Answer (score 1):

Your second derivative expression seems to be wrong at the end.
$$
f_x+f_yf=e^xy+e^x(e^xy+1)=e^x((1+e^x)y+1)
$$
And yes, it is a second order method like modified or improved Euler, so a factor of $1/16$ when the step size is divided by 4 is to be expected.

Comment: You are correct but could you provide a more analytical reason as to the second part? Thank you in advance

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly is to prove. The local truncation error is of order 2, $\frac{y(t+h)-y(t)}{h}-\Phi_f(t,y(t),h)=O(h^2)$, where $\Phi_f$ symbolizes the method step. There is a general procedure for one-step methods on how this local error order transfers to the global error, key is that $f$ and relevant derivatives are locally Lipschitz.